# i am trying to create a register activity in android but my controls are not working validation

Tags: java, android

i am trying to create a register activity in android my control goes to registration method but and also i have done validation when i click on signUp it directly goes to next activity without validating or registering
when i start the application
and come to signup activity it work properly 
also the log messages are printing
but after the register method called nothing is working
i havent given intent for next activity still it is going to next activity
here is the code i have written

```
package com.ap.pran;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener; 
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ProgressBar progressBar;
EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextMobileNo, editTextVehicleNo, editTextName;
private static final String TAG = " ANAND MESSAGE";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    Log.i(TAG, "in onCreate1");
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    editTextMobileNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMobileNo);
    editTextVehicleNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVehicleNo);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.SignIn).setOnClickListener(this);

}


private void registerUser() {
    Log.i(TAG, "In register method");
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("Email is required !!!");
        editTextEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty()) {

        editTextPassword.setError("Password is required !!!");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.length()<6){
        editTextPassword.setError("Password length must be greater than 6");
        editTextPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"User Registred !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "User Registration Failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });




}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonSignUp:
            Log.i(TAG, "In case 1");
            registerUser();
            break;

        case R.id.SignIn:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            Log.i(TAG, "In case 2");
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Update your question it is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

check the validation by using the following way

```
if (email .equals("")
{//Print your error
}else if (password.equals("")
{//Print your error}
else if(!email.matches(emailPattren)
{//Print your error}
else if
(Password.length()<6)
{//Print your error}
else
{
Intent intent=new Intent (first.this,second.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```